# How to dynamically add LinearLayout in a Listview?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have created a `listview` with Custom Adapter, I wish to add following structure dynamically depending on database entry.

```
LinearLayout (Vertical)
TextView 
LinearLayout (Horizontal)
TextView 
TextView
```

---- this text view will be dynamic can be 2,3 or more depending on the database

I have written following code just to display the structure dynamically.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_info_item, null);
        //convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_info_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cinema_info_item_iv);
        holder.movieNameTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cinema_info_item_movie_name_tv);
        holder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        // add this linearlayout dynamically for each listview item
        LinearLayout parent_linear = new LinearLayout(activity);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(20, 5, 20, 5);
        parent_linear.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        parent_linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        parent_linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        //children of parent linear layout
        TextView tvStatus = new TextView(activity);
        tvStatus.setText("status");

        LinearLayout TimeLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);

        TimeLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TimeLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        parent_linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        parent_linear.removeAllViews();
        parent_linear.addView(tvStatus);
        parent_linear.addView(TimeLinearLayout);

        //children of layout2 LinearLayout
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(activity);
        tv1.setText("1");
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(activity);
        tv1.setText("2");
        TextView tv3 = new TextView(activity);
        tv1.setText("3");
        TextView tv4 = new TextView(activity);
        tv1.setText("4");

        TimeLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
        TimeLinearLayout.addView(tv1);
        TimeLinearLayout.addView(tv2);
        TimeLinearLayout.addView(tv3);
        TimeLinearLayout.addView(tv4);

    return convertView;
}
```

Please tell me why `linearlayout` is not getting display
I have tried :

```
convertView.addView(LinearLayout);
```

But this does not work, it does not display the linear layout on screen when run.

Comment: please help me out with this isssue

Comment: Please also post the list row item layout, cinema_info_item.xml.

Answer (score 1):

First call TimeLinearLayout.removeAllViews(); then try to add any other view

Comment: I have tried both, placing the code outside if condition and also call removeAllViews(). still, it is not visible, i have updated the code above